# Read next html tag using PHP

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

This is my HTML part of code:

```
<ul>
    <li> something,,,,... </li>
    <li> something,,,,... </li>
    <li> something,,,,... </li>
    <li> something,,,,... </li>
    <li>
        <h5>Price</h5>
        <span>100$</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my php I am using [php-simple-dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for finding tags. So php part looks something like this:

```
    foreach($html->find("li") as $li)
    {

        if(strpos($li->plaintext,"<h5>Price</h5>") !== false)
        {
            var_dump($li->plaintext); // result: string("<h5>Price</h5><span>100$</span>")
        }
    }
```

I have some other idea:

```
    foreach($html->find("h5") as $h5)
    {

        if(strpos($h5->plaintext,"Price") !== false)
        {
            // finding some way to read next tag
        }
    }
```

What I need ?

I need to get `<span>` value. This is example, in real code there are more tags and multiple spans in one `<li>`. But point is that next tag contain wanted information.

Comment: where is the html coming from? If you have access to the source it makes no sense to be parsing it in php

Comment: @andrew I am crawling some webpage, and getting info from that page. I have up {$html = file_get_html($website_url);}

Comment: ok I havn't tried php-simple-dom. prob `var_dump($h5->find("span"));` and seee how that worked out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure how many tags could be in one `<li>`, but I belive `<span>` you are looking for is always after `<h5>`. You can use method `$e->next_sibling()` as follows:

```
foreach ($html->find('li h5') as $h5) {
    $price = $h5->next_sibling();
    echo $price->plaintext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get a value of a specific tag, you could find [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) useful.

Return Values

> A new DOMNodeList object containing all the matched elements.

Here is how you would use it:

```
$html = <<< HTML
<ul>
    <li> something,,,,... </li>
    <li> something,,,,... </li>
    <li> something,,,,... </li>
    <li> something,,,,... </li>
    <li>
        <h5>Price</h5>
        <span>100$</span>
    </li>
</ul>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($html);
$prices = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
foreach ($prices as $price) {
    echo $price->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

The above example will output: `100$`

Go ahead and try it with several prices. It works as excepted.

You might also find the [DOM documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) useful.